# If two numbers are found to be equal how would one take the first number inputted

Tags: c++, function, loops

I have gotten all of my program to work exactly how it should except for the very end.

At the end when the 'winnerAvg' and 'winnerName' are outputted to the screen if multiple names have the same average all of them will be printed to the screen.

What I was wondering was if there was a way to get only the first name inputted with that average to be outputted to the screen. Instead of all that apply.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>   //for name entry of contestants
#include <iomanip>  //rounding and point perceision
#include <fstream>  //write names and averages to a file for storage

using namespace std;

double calcAvgScore(int, int, int, int, int);   //calculates the average after the highest and lowest scores are found 
double findHighest(int, int, int, int, int);    //finds the highest of the 5 scores 
double findLowest(int, int, int, int, int);     //finds the lowest of the 5 scores

int main()
{
string cName;   //name of the contestant
int jScore1, jScore2, jScore3, jScore4, jScore5;    //scores of each judge
double AvgScore;    //average of the scores
ofstream outFile;

outFile.open("NamesAndAverage.txt");    //creation and opening of text file where the names and averages will be stored

cout << "All judges' scores are from 1 to 10" << endl;
cout << " " << endl;

for (int count = 1;; count++)   //loop to keep track of number of Contestants and exits when Done is entered
{
    cout << " " << endl;
    if (count = 1)
        cout << "Please enter the name of Contestant #" << count << ". If there are no Contestants enter ""Done""" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Please enter the name of Contestant #" << count << ". If there are no more Contestants please enter ""Done""" << endl;
    cin >> cName;
    if (cName == "Done")
        break;

    cout << " " << endl;

    cout << "Please enter the score from Judge 1 ";
    cin >> jScore1;
    while (jScore1 < 1 || jScore1 > 10)
    {
        cout << "scores must be from 1 to 10" << endl;
        cout << "Please re-enter the score from Judge1 ";
        cin >> jScore1;
    }
    cout << "Please enter the score from Judge 2 ";
    cin >> jScore2;
    while (jScore2 < 1 || jScore2 > 10)
    {
        cout << "scores must be from 1 to 10" << endl;
        cout << "Please re-enter the score from Judge2 ";
        cin >> jScore2;
    }
    cout << "Please enter the score from Judge 3 ";
    cin >> jScore3;
    while (jScore3 < 1 || jScore3 > 10)
    {
        cout << "scores must be from 1 to 10" << endl;
        cout << "Please re-enter the score from Judge3 ";
        cin >> jScore3;
    }
    cout << "Please enter the score from Judge 4 ";
    cin >> jScore4;
    while (jScore4 < 1 || jScore4 > 10)
    {
        cout << "scores must be from 1 to 10" << endl;
        cout << "Please re-enter the score from Judge4 ";
        cin >> jScore4;
    }
    cout << "Please enter the score from Judge 5 ";
    cin >> jScore5;
    while (jScore5 < 1 || jScore5 > 10)
    {
        cout << "scores must be from 1 to 10" << endl;
        cout << "Please re-enter the score from Judge5 ";
        cin >> jScore5;
    }

    double AvgScore = calcAvgScore(jScore1, jScore2, jScore3, jScore4, jScore5);    //call to function
    outFile << cName << " " << AvgScore;    //writing variables to the file
}
outFile.close();


cout << " " << endl;
cout << " "<<endl;

double winnerScore = 0;     //variable for the highest average
string winnerName = "Null"; //variable for name with highest average
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("NamesAndAverage.txt");

while (inFile >> cName >> AvgScore) //reading variables from file
{
    if (AvgScore > winnerScore)
        winnerScore = AvgScore;

    if (AvgScore == winnerScore)
        winnerName=cName;

}
cout << "The winner is " << winnerName << " with a score of " << setprecision(2) << fixed << winnerScore << endl;


system("pause");
return 0;
}




double calcAvgScore(int jScore1, int jScore2, int jScore3, int jScore4, int jScore5)
{
double highest = findHighest(jScore1, jScore2, jScore3, jScore4, jScore5);
double lowest = findLowest(jScore1, jScore2, jScore3, jScore4, jScore5);
double total = (jScore1 + jScore2 + jScore3 + jScore4 + jScore5 - highest - lowest);
double AvgScore = (total / 3);
cout << "inside Average function Avg= " << AvgScore << endl;
return AvgScore;
}


double findHighest(int jScore1, int jScore2, int jScore3, int jScore4, int jScore5)
{
double highest = 0;
if (jScore1 > highest)
    highest = jScore1;
if (jScore2 > highest)
    highest = jScore2;
if (jScore3 > highest)
    highest = jScore3;
if (jScore4 > highest)
    highest = jScore4;
if (jScore5 > highest)
    highest = jScore5;
cout << "inside highest function highest = " << highest << endl;
return highest;
}


double findLowest(int jScore1, int jScore2, int jScore3, int jScore4, int jScore5)
{
double lowest = 10;
if (jScore1 < lowest)
    lowest = jScore1;
if (jScore2 < lowest)
    lowest = jScore2;
if (jScore3 < lowest)
    lowest = jScore3;
if (jScore4 < lowest)
    lowest = jScore4;
if (jScore5 < lowest)
    lowest = jScore5;
cout << "inside lowest function lowest= " << lowest << endl;
return lowest;
}
```

Comment: If they are equal, who cares which one it is?

Comment: Yes there is a way. Calculate the winning score first, then read all the scores again and print out the first one that has the winning score.

Comment: It's not an uncommon problem to need to "keep the first one I found that matches some criteria". It's really just a case of "not replacing it" until you find something that is "better" [not just equal or better].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
if (AvgScore > winnerScore)
    winnerScore = AvgScore;

if (AvgScore == winnerScore)
    winnerName=cName;
```

to:

```
if (AvgScore > winnerScore)
{
    winnerScore = AvgScore;
    winnerName = cName;
}
```

should do the trick - in other words, don't update name unless you are also updating the score. If the score is equal, the FIRST found will be the "winner".